# CATransaction + UIView on iOS 3.2

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, catransaction

I need to implement very custom animation on iOS 3.2
So, neither I can't use block animations nor UIKit animations before 4.0. I try to use Core Animation.

Here's my code:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration: 3.0];
[CATransaction setDisableActions: YES];
someView.frame = CGRectMake(endX, 0, endWidth, height); 
// a lot of another property changes
[CATransaction commit];
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work: views change size/opacity immediately, without any animation.

Here's my attempts:

- I set new frame not to view but to its layer (someView.layer.frame = ...) - it was even worse because subviews of view weren't resized.
- I set disable action option to YES and NO.

Solution requirements:

- iOS 3.2 must be supported (no blocks).
- Animations must be applied to different views (consequently, to different layers).
- Animation curve is difficult enough, so I can't use pre-defined animation curves (or, by CA language, MediaTimingFunction).

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted explicitly disables animations. This line is the culprit:

```
[CATransaction setDisableActions: YES];
```

By making that call, all the changes made in your transaction will be committed immediately, without animating. Get rid of that line and the changes should animate.

If you need a custom curve you might want to use a CABasicAnimation, as someone else suggested. Indeed, CAAnimation objects only apply to a single layer, so you'd have to create multiple CAAnimation objects.

Alternately, you should be able to use the CATransaction method setAnimationTimingFunction, and pass it a custom timing function that you create. See the CAMediaTimingFunction class reference. Specifically take a look at the method functionWithControlPoints::::, which lets you create a timing function by specifying the control points for a bezier curve that describes your timing function. You are limited to a single cubic bezier that starts at 0,0 and ends at 1,1. There is no direct support for more complex timing functions, although I have seen hacks that achieve more complex effects.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about if this is what you want or not, but you could use UIView animations

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
someView.frame = CGRectMake(endX, 0, endWidth, height); 
// a lot of another property changes
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Animation curve is too difficult, I can't use UIView animation methods. I've updated the question and add requirement of MediaTimingFunction.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have a custom timing function then you can do it with a CABasicAnimation. You can create a custom timing function (which is a bezier curve from (0,0) to (1,1) with two control points that you can specify.

If that is not enough for you (if you need more than 2 control points for your timing function) then you would have to use a CAKeyframeAnumation. Then you can specify as many values as you want (using the `values` property (an array).

In both cases you would create a animation object for the keypath "frame" and add the animation to the views layer. Note that animating a property explicitly doesn't change the value so after the animation te frame will go back to its original value unless you both animate *and* change the value

Comment: Yes, I've considered to use BasicAnimation, but, as I understood, it's applied to one layer. I should animate more than one view.

Comment: You can use an animation group to apply multiple animations the the same layer but if you want to apply them to different layers then you need a transaction. The good thing about animation groups is that you can configure them (like setting the timing) and it will apply to all the animations in that group. It won't work as nice if you require key frame animations though. Maybe you can have a method that returns the suitable array for your "to" and "from" value and use it go get the same timing for all animations (if you require key frames)